# new version of glibc returns wrong timezone

Tags: timezone, glibc

This SO thread [Why does glibc “timezone” global not agree with system time on DST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635780/why-does-glibc-timezone-global-not-agree-with-system-time-on-dst) is not a solution for my problem.

My system has `glibc 2.11.3` and for my project I compiled `glibc 2.22`. I ran `make localedata/install-locales`.

This MCVE displays the correct time only when linked against the old `glibc` version. Linking it against the new `glibc` version it displays the UTC time:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct tm * tmNow;
    time_t dtNow;
    char sBuffer [100];

    tzset();

    time( &dtNow );
    tmNow = localtime( &dtNow );

    strftime( sBuffer, sizeof(sBuffer), "%Y-%m-%d %T", tmNow );
    printf("%ld - %s\n", timezone, sBuffer);
}
```

When I try to run `tzselect` in the `bin/` directory of the new `glibc` version I get this error:

```
./tzselect: line 171: /usr/glibc/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab: No such file or directory
./tzselect: time zone files are not set up correctly
```

More or less it says all but for the moment I am not capable to find out how to set up the file `/usr/glibc/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab`.

How do I set up the timezone for the **new** `glibc` version permanently?

**I do not want to use the TZ variable**!

**UPDATE**:
Using the `TZ` variable does not change anything. I guess I did not configure correctly the new `glibc` version.

**UPDATE**: Copying the existing `/usr/share/zoneinfo` system directory into the new `/usr/glibc/share/zoneinfo` directory at least fixed the problem with the `TZ` variable. But as long the `TZ` variable is not set the new `glibc` version does not recognize the correct timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened the new `libc.so.6` library with `vi` and searched for `localtime`.

The hard coded directory where the new `glibc` version was looking for `localtime` is set to `/usr/glibc/etc`.

Then it was an easy task: I ran the command

> `ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Vienna /usr/glibc/etc/localtime`

and now the `localtime` is recognized correctly in the new `glibc` version without using the `TZ` variable.